# Elegant way to concatenate string in one column to several columns in df

Tags: python, pandas, time, string-concatenation

I have a df structured as so:

```
   CUID    DATE        T1         T2         T3
0  1000   5/5/2016   3:58:54    4:02:00    4:15:05
1  1001   5/6/2016  17:23:39   17:24:00   17:44:32
2  1002   5/7/2016  18:20:50   18:22:00   18:37:34
3  1003   5/7/2016  21:30:29   21:35:00   21:45:51
4  1004   5/9/2016  22:33:19   22:34:00   22:41:54
...
```

I want to take the date (string) and concatenate to each time string (i.e., T1, T2, T3). In other words, i want it to look like this:

```
  CUID    DATE             T1                  T2                 T3
0  1000   5/5/2016  5/5/2016 3:58:54    5/5/2016 4:02:00   5/5/2016 4:15:05
1  1001   5/6/2016  5/5/2016 17:23:39   5/5/2016 17:24:00  5/5/2016 17:44:32
2  1002   5/7/2016  5/5/2016 18:20:50   5/5/2016 18:22:00  5/5/2016 18:37:34
3  1003   5/7/2016  5/5/2016 21:30:29   5/5/2016 21:35:00  5/5/2016 21:45:51
4  1004   5/9/2016  5/5/2016 22:33:19   5/5/2016 22:34:00  5/5/2016 22:41:54
...
```

I know I can do this using the following code:

```
df['T1'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE.str.cat(' ' + df['T1']))
df['T2'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE.str.cat(' ' + df['T2']))
df['T3'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE.str.cat(' ' + df['T3']))
```

But I was wondering if there was a more elegant/efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `apply` and in the `lambda` just add the DATE column with a space and the column of interest.

Here `apply` will iterate over the sub-selected columns:

```
In[8]:
df.loc[:,'T1':] = df.loc[:,'T1':].apply(lambda x: df['DATE'] + ' ' + x)
df

Out[8]:
CUID      DATE                 T1                 T2                 T3
0  1000  5/5/2016   5/5/2016 3:58:54   5/5/2016 4:02:00   5/5/2016 4:15:05
1  1001  5/6/2016  5/6/2016 17:23:39  5/6/2016 17:24:00  5/6/2016 17:44:32
2  1002  5/7/2016  5/7/2016 18:20:50  5/7/2016 18:22:00  5/7/2016 18:37:34
3  1003  5/7/2016  5/7/2016 21:30:29  5/7/2016 21:35:00  5/7/2016 21:45:51
4  1004  5/9/2016  5/9/2016 22:33:19  5/9/2016 22:34:00  5/9/2016 22:41:54
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `loc` here instead of `ix`?

Comment: @DSM that's true, will update, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Not a pandas feature but you could reduce the code duplication with a simple loop:

```
for column in ['T1', 'T2', 'T3']:
    df[column] = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE.str.cat(' ' + df[column]))
```

Comment: This works, too. But, I am trying to stay away from loop because they aren't very efficient in Python.

Comment: @user2970409: that's true, but small loops aren't often a problem.  And `apply` uses a slow loop as opposed to vectorized functions anyhow.

Comment: I didn't know apply uses a loop. Good to know.